# how to find month of quarter not a quarter of month

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem to the find the month of quarter, but I only want to enter a month between 1 and 3.

Suppose I enter 3, then the quarter will be 1 and the month will be 3. And if I enter 8, then the quarter will be 3 and the month will be 2. If I enter 12, then the quarter will be 4 and the month will be 3.

The quarter will be found using this formula:

```
quarter=((month-1)/3)+1
```

Does anyone know of a formula to find the month?

Comment: Your tried code is?

Comment: Helpful metric: if your question tags more than one language, it's probably too broad for stack overflow's format. If it tags more than two, it's almost definitely too broad.

Comment: Please don't begin posts with "Respected Sir".  Many users of Stack Overflow are women.

Comment: `month - (quarter-1)*3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
monthOfQuarter = ((month - 1) % 3) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the modulus operator.

Search the language reference for this.